# NameError: x_train is not deinfed

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I keep getting this error.  I am building a prediction model but can't seem to get passed this

```
X_train = []
y_train = []

for i in range(100, data_training_array.shape[0]):
    x_train.append(data_training_array[i-100: i])
    y_train.append(data_training_array[i, 0])
    
x_train, y_train = np.array(x_train), np.array(y_train)
```

---

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_34316/1046987676.py in 
3
4 for i in range(100, data_training_array.shape[0]):
----> 5     x_train.append(data_training_array[i-100: i])
6     y_train.append(data_training_array[i, 0])
7

NameError: name 'x_train' is not defined

Comment: You have a typo.  You have defined `X_train` with a capital X and then are referring to it later as `x_train` with a lowercase x.

Answer (score 0):

`X_train` is capitalized when you initialize it, but you refer to it as `x_train` in the rest of your code. Lowercase `x_train = []` or capitalize it in the rest of the code.